# rank(A) $\le$ $n-1$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix with each entry equal to $\pm1,0$ such that every column has exactly one $+1$ and exactly one $-1$. Which one of the following is true?

1. $\text{rank}(A) \leq (n-1)$
2. $\text{rank}(A) \leq m$
3. $n\le m$
4. $n-1\le m$

Show that 1. is the correct alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rank is the dimension of the image of $A$. You can verify, that the image lies in the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix})$, which has dimension $n-1$.

Comment: @ Julian: Can you elaborate your point which says that image lies in the orthogonal complement of span{(⎛⎝1⎜⎜1⋮...1⎞⎠1)'⎟⎟$, which has dimension n−1.

Comment: Every column of A consists of exactly one 1, one -1 and zeros. So the image of A is generated by elements y, that satisfy <y,(1,...,1)>=0, which says that the image itself is orthogonal to this vector. I.p. there is a nontrivial vector, that is not contained in im(A), so the dimension of im(A) is at most n-1.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $A= (a_{ij}) \in Mat_{n\times m} (\mathbb{Z})$. Note that
$$rank\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1m}\\ 
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2m}\\  
*&*&*&*\\ 
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nm}\\ 
\end{bmatrix} = rank \begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k1}& \sum_{k=1}^n a_{k2}&\ldots&\sum_{k=1}^n a_{km}\\ 
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2m}\\  
*&*&*&*\\ 
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nm}\\  
\end{bmatrix}$$
Or,
$$rank\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{1m}\\ 
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2m}\\  
*&*&*&*\\ 
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nm}\\ 
\end{bmatrix} = rank \begin{bmatrix}
0& 0&\ldots&0\\ 
a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2m}\\  
*&*&*&*\\ 
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nm}\\  
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus $rank (A) \leq n-1$.